# Can Colloportus be broken by Alohomora?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

I wanted to know- Colloportus seems to be a spell that locks a door/something.

Alohomora seems to be a spell that unlocks a door/something.

So can Alohomora break Colloportus?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely, we see this at least as early as *The Order of the Phoenix*, where Hermione's *Colloportus* is undone by *Alohomora*.

> *'Colloportus!'* gasped Hermione and the door sealed itself with an odd squelching noise.
>
> [...]
>
> They were almost there when Harry heard something large and heavy collide with the door Hermione had charmed shut.
>
> 'Stand aside!' said a rough voice. *'Alohomora!'*
>
> As the door flew open, Harry, Hermione and Neville dived under desks.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.695 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 35, *Beyond the Veil*

So this was firmly established in the original series as a key limitation of *Colloportus* /power of *Alohomora* and isn't an innovation of *The Cursed Child*. (Just for the benefit of those who might be wondering about *The Cursed Child*'s tendency to reimagine earlier events and information).

Comment: Real story? Not a fan of Cursed Child then?

Comment: Makes one wonder why they bother locking doors! Hermione knew how to unlock even magically locked ones by age 11 or 12.

Comment: @ThruGog I seem to remember there was a stronger door locking charm/bewitchment/whatever but presumably the DA members didn't know it. I don't think we ever see it being used, either, but I'm sure I remember *Alohomora* failing, e.g. on Umbridge's door

Comment: @Au101 - Yes I think you're right actually. And you can have like an alarm spell and barriers and so on. But might as well not bother with old Colloportus

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As shown in Cursed Child,

> DELPHI: Potter. Colloportus!
>
> ...
>
> *ALBUS opens both doors with his wand.*
>
> ALBUS: Alohomora! Alohomora!

There we see Delphi using Colloportus, and Albus breaking it with Alohomora.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check on Wikia.

> Colloportus is a charm which makes a door lock. It can be redone by Alohomora.

[Link](http://harrypotterwiki2.wikia.com/wiki/Colloportus)